# free(temp) frees the rear of my queue. How do I free it

Tags: c, pointers, queue

Ok so I have a function to print a queue. I use a temp Node to iterate through the linked list.
When I try to free the temporary node, it also frees the rear of my queue (the last node inside the queue)

```
struct QNode *temp = q->front;

printf("Queue: %d", temp->value);
while (temp->next != NULL)
{
    temp = temp->next;
    printf(" -> %d", temp->value);
}
printf("\n");

free(temp);
```

I have a very long algorithm and If i dont free the temp I will have hundreds of thousands of trash memory. And I cant afford it

Comment: How is it allocated in the first place?

Comment: This is unclear to me. `temp` **is** pointing to the last node so of cause it frees the last node. What did you expect?

Comment: If you don't want to remove the last node, simply delete the line `free(temp)`. `temp` itself is a variable with automatic storage duration so you don't need to "free" `temp`. It will be destroyed automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is one `free` per `malloc`, since you are not allocating space for your temporary node (is just a pointer to the front), you dont have to call `free`, just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My valgrind gave me error because my queue was not freed ad the end. I though it was because of temp but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have misunderstood what `free(temp)` is doing.

`free(temp)` will **not** free `temp` Instead it will free the node that `temp` **points** to.

After your loop, `temp` points to the last node in your list so calling `free(temp)` will **free the last node**. Your linked list will be broken because the node before the last node now points to a free'ed object.

Misunderstanding number two seems to be that `temp` needs to be free'ed. **It doesn't**.

`temp` is an object with automatic storage duration (aka a local variable). It will be destroyed automatically when the function returns.

Like:

```
void printList(...)
{
    struct QNode *temp = q->front;  // temp is just a local variable

    printf("Queue: %d", temp->value);
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        printf(" -> %d", temp->value);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // free(temp);   Don't call free on temp
    //               temp will be automatically destroyed once the function completes
}
```

Comment: yes. I realised that the valgrind error was due to not freeing the queue at the end. I thought that this temp was the problem but I was wrong. Thank you for the answer